# Servlets-Session attribute becoming NULL

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I am new to servlets and jsp. In my program the flow is as below:

`loginpage.html` -> `controller`(servlet - here I created session like this)

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("uid", uname);
System.out.println("session:"+session.getAttribute("uid"));// shows the value of uid
```

->`create_user.html`-> `conroller`( now it shows `uid` value as null)->`view_customers.jsp` (need `uid` value here but its *null*).

How to avoid session attribute from becoming null? Thanks in advance!

Comment: First check whether you uname is null or not in this code.

Comment: `Session#getSession(true);` and `Session.getSession()` is same. that says : `if the request does not have a session, creates one.`

Comment: @ambarox uname is not null in the code...

Comment: @Braj Thnk u..I am aware of dat..

Comment: On user side information about session is stored in cookies by browser. Maybe your cookie was either deleted or wasn't created at first place. Maybe your browser is blocking cookies, or your application sets very short time to live like. Maybe you have somewhere code similar to `session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0)`, or in deployment descriptor (web.xml file) configuration like `<session-config><session-timeout>0</session-timeout></session-config>`.

Comment: **try with request attribute to validate it.**

Answer (score 0):

**How to avoid session attribute from becoming null?**

> You can monitor the attribute state (added/removed/replaced) in `session scope` using `HttpSessionAttributeListener`.

Sample code:

```
public class MySessionAttributeListener implements HttpSessionAttributeListener {

    public MySessionAttributeListener() {
    }

    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent sessionBindingEvent) {

        // Get the session
        HttpSession session = sessionBindingEvent.getSession();

        // Log some information
        System.out.println("[SessionAttr] " + new java.util.Date()
                + " Attribute added, session " + session + ": " + sessionBindingEvent.getName()
                + "=" + sessionBindingEvent.getValue());
    }

    public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent sessionBindingEvent) {

        // Get the session
        HttpSession session = sessionBindingEvent.getSession();

        // Log some information
        System.out.println("[SessionAttr] " + new java.util.Date()
                + " Attribute removed, session " + session + ": "
                + sessionBindingEvent.getName());
    }

    public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent sessionBindingEvent) {

        // Get the session
        HttpSession session = sessionBindingEvent.getSession();

        // Log some information
        System.out.println("[SessionAttr] " + new java.util.Date()
                + " Attribute replaced, session " + session + ": "
                + sessionBindingEvent.getName() + "=" + sessionBindingEvent.getValue());
    }
}
```

web.xml: (add below line in web.xml)

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.x.y.z.MySessionAttributeListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```