# Best practices for indicating a field has been modified in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, getter-setter

My application has several key objects whose fields are accessed by multiple presenters.  Currently, my use of getters/setters is limited to cases in which validation is required.  I'd like to keep track of whether the field values have been updated (and therefore require database update).  To do so, I'm considering adding boolean flags isDirty (to indicate that the current value differs from the retrieved or default) and isDeleted (to indicate whether the record(s) associated with an object should be removed).  Adding such flags to the class would require either (a) using setters and setting the flag values in the setter when the field is updated) or (b) Forgoing setters but requiring any code that modified a field value to also set the flags (clearly error prone).  Is there a more elegant way to keep track of field meta-data?

Comment: What are these key objects? where does it reside in the project?

Comment: Here's a solution that just occurred to me: store copy of object  retrieved from DB prior to potential updates ("original").  Before saving to DB compare current object to (a) "original", and (b) "default"=new object().  Compare by creating equals() that uses all fields.  If either differs, then object has been updated and must be saved...

Comment: How will you check for the difference? removed/added/replaced?

Comment: In this case you have to change a lot of code wherever you are doing DB operation.

Comment: If object is in session then you can easily monitor the state because it works as listener.

Comment: Since delete/remove happens on a per-object basis rather than field, I can handle that separately with a deleteXyzObject() invocation.  For updates to field values I would use equals() as described above instead of keeping track of flags.  In other words, I'd assess the state at the end (just before DB update) instead of keeping track of it all along.  What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, I could store these fields in the http session, but that would require RPC calls to the servlet every time the user makes a change on the UI.  This is something I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your line `Each app session has at most one of each` I asked you in my first comment-  `where does it reside in the project?`

Answer (score 0):

> If object is stored as session attribute then you can monitor the attribute state (added/removed/replaced) in `session scope` using [HttpSessionAttributeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html).

I have already posted a sample code on [Servlets-Session attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328111/servlets-session-attribute-becoming-null/23328333#23328333). Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't believe this solution addresses my question.  This is a server-side solution.  My question is about keeping track of object state on the UI.  The UI first needs to detect a change in the object state before it launches an RPC call to the server to update a session attribute.